# Prove that if $B$ is an antisymmetric matrix, then $\det(B+I) \neq 0$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

Prove that if $B$ is an antisymmetric matrix with real entries, then $\det(B+I) \neq 0$.

Comment: What do you know about the eigenvalues of $B$?

Comment: If you have no idea about eigenvalues, notice that $x^T B x = 0$ for every $x$.

Comment: What I do not understand. Other questions which, just as this one, show no own effort, get downvoted. Why not this one? It makes no sense.

Comment: Because he is a good boy ;)

Comment: This question is equivalent to https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1276665/if-a-is-an-antisymmetric-matrix-then-ai-is-invertible?rq=1 .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The matrix $B$ satisfies $B^T=-B$; suppose $\det(B+I)=0$; then there exists $x\ne0$ such that $(B+I)x=0$. It follows that $Bx=-x$ and so
$$
x^TBx=-x^Tx
$$
Transpose both sides, getting
$$
x^TB^Tx=-x^Tx
$$
and use the hypothesis $B^T=-B$ to get a contradiction.

(It can be made without contradiction, of course.)