# If $A$ is an invertible matrix then is $A - I$ antisymmetric?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

The opposite statement of the title:

> If A is antisymmetric, then A + I is invertible.

has been already asked (example [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1276665/if-a-is-an-antisymmetric-matrix-then-ai-is-invertible)). However I would like to know if the following is true:

> If A is an invertible matrix, then is B = A - I is an antisymmetric matrix?

If yes, what is the proof?

Comment: No. take any matrix $C$, if you multiply it by a small enough number $\epsilon$, $A = 1 + \epsilon C$ will be invertible.

Comment: The set of invertible matrices $\{A\mid\det A\neq0\}$ is $n^2$-dimensional, so the shifted set $\{A-I\mid\det A\neq0\}$ is also $n^2$-dimensional, while the set of antisymmetric matrices $\{A\mid A^T=-A\}$ is $\frac{n(n-1)}{2}$-dimensional. A high-dimensional thing cannot be a subset of a low-dimensional thing.

Comment: @mr_e_man, very nice!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $A=2I$ and then $B=I$.  $B$ is invertible but $A$ is not antisymmetric.

That answered the question before the edit.  The answer is the same after the edit:  no.

After the edit to the question:

$A$ and $B$ as defined above.  $A$ is invertible, $B$ is not antisymmetric.